# How to access data from presigned url(s) on S3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am fairly new to using AWS S3 and I am bit lost on how to extract data from a presigned url link. So currently, I was given the `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key`, and `region_name`. However, I am lost on how to extract the presigned url because I do see that the presigned url also has an `AWS access key id`, `expiration time`, `.json`, `response-content-disposition`,`response-content-type`, and `Signature`. I am also not sure what to put down as my key for the `Params`.

Other than that, when I do run the code(I provided an incorrect key), I am getting an `InvalidRequest The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported`.

Example presigned url link:

`https://video_annotations.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/annotations/sub-folder1/9162dn28sd78n.json?respone-content-disposition=attachment$6B%50filename%9D812jad9.json&respone-content-type=application%3Fjson&AWSAccessKeyID=different_aws_access_key_id&Signature=pAKSR97&Expires=1661271906`

This is what I currently have for my Code:

```
client = boto3.client(
   's3',
   aws_access_key_id = 'my_aws_access_key_id',
   aws_secret_access_key = 'my_aws_secret_access_key',
   region_name = 'my_region_name'
)

url = client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                    Params={
                                        'Bucket':'video_annotations',
                                        'Key':'???',
                                    },
                                    ExpiresIn=1661271906)
print(url)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The key is just the path of the object in bucket, for `https://video_annotations.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/annotations/sub-folder1/9162dn28sd78n.json?respone-content-disposition=attachment$6B%50filename%9D812jad9.json&respone-content-type=application%3Fjson&AWSAccessKeyID=different_aws_access_key_id&Signature=pAKSR97&Expires=1661271906`, the key would be `folder1/annotations/sub-folder1/9162dn28sd78n.json`

Comment: Hi @Tony Yip, I just fixed the key and I am now getting a new error: `AccessDeniedInvalid date(should be seconds since epoch)`. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Because `ExpiresIn` should be time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid. Take a look at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

Comment: So is my `ExpiresIn` value incorrect? I assumed that the presigned url `Expires=1661271906` would be the `ExpiresIn` value?

Comment: `Expires` is computed from current timestamp + `ExpiresIn`, so it should be to seconds until expiry, not timestamp, try with `ExpiresIn=3600`. Document: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Comment: Looks like I am getting this error because I got the internal/external buckets confused. Looks like I am going to have to create a python request instead.

Comment: Huh? Can you please Edit your question to add details of your current problem? (Keep the old information there for future reference, but please _add_ details of your current situation.)